# What is Google Analytics data retention period?

Tags: google-analytics

What is Google Analytics data retention period? i.e. How long are we able to view the data in GA account before it is no longer view able?

Right now, we are using a free Google Analytics account.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to the data retention policy of a company instead of a specific programming question.

Answer (score 4):

It differs for the type of GA account you have. For GA Premium the data retention period is 3 years while that for GA standard its 25 months.

---

**Update from google** :

The rules are 2 years for Standard and 3 years for Premium. However this is not being enforced at the moment and never have been  - you should see all of the data from the date you started collecting. Note that this may be enforced at some point in the future.

[image]

Comment: Would you mind posting documentation link to where you have found this information?   Considering that I have several accounts that are more then 5 years old and still have data in them I am wondering where you are getting your information from.

Comment: @DaImTo : The data stays longer than what it supposed to be. I mean the data is never deleted. The documentation for GA accounts have changed a lot and now I dont have any trusted links, but the figures were the same as I mentioned

Comment: If the OFFICAL documentation doesn't say that data is removed then why would you tell someone that it isn't.  If I write a blog post that says the first of April every year all your numbers in Google Analytics will be doubled will that be true as well?  Trust Googles OFFICAL documentation.

Comment: @DaImTo : It was there before in the official documentation.

Comment: At one time there was books that said the world was flat, that has also been corrected.   If it was there before maybe and isn't now maybe things have changed in the 10 years GA has been live.  Please link to the documentation if you can find it I really need to know if Google is going to delete my data.

Comment: @DaImTo : I have emailed google for this query. I will update as soon as they return to me

Comment: I emailed it to the Dev team see who hears back first :)

Comment: @DaImTo :Got the reply : "The rules are 2 years for Standard and 3 years for Premium. However this is not being enforced at the moment and never have been  - you should see all of the data from the date you started collecting. Note that this may be enforced at some point in the future."

Comment: edit your question and add a screen shot or copy of your email and I will delete mine.